# Is there a word to express: 'An object that once seen compels the viewer to perform a certain action'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to express: An object that once seen compels the viewer to perform a certain action.

Comment: Please add an example.  And what do you mean by "once seen".  Does the viewer perform the action over and over again, having seen the object once?  Or do you mean "when seen"?  "Such as, a chocolate sundae, when seen, compels the viewer to eat it. What is the word for this?"

Comment: Do you want a word for the object? the compulsion? What?

Comment: I can think of several "objects", if the "certain action" is to vomit.

Comment: A stop sign? A speed limit sign? A "Reduced-Speed Curve Ahead" sign? A "No Right Turn on Red, 8AM - 4PM" sign? And so on. Don

Comment: @ab2 I'd think each time you see the object you have to perform the action.  The chocolate sundae is a good example, but I was hoping for something even more compulsive.

Comment: @BrianTung I'm looking for the word for the object.

Comment: @rhetorician Plenty of people ignore traffic signs.

Comment: The concept would be more like you look at the object and you are then somehow mysteriously forced, likely against your will, to perform the action.

Comment: Something like "unignorable"?

Comment: Trigger?  If I see an object and I compulsively perform an action, that object triggers the action.

Comment: How about "the muzzle of a 12-gauge shotgun"? Oops, more than one word.

Comment: Yes, there is precisely such a word: it is **compelling** (or **a compelling object** if you want a noun), [defined by Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compelling) as "strong and forceful: causing you to feel you must do something".

Answer (score 1):

The object could be called a [*catalyst*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/catalyst) for the action, although it sounds like you're looking for something with a more mysterious, magical force rather than just a cause of action.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like a **talisman** or a **fetish**.

Comment: Based on the discussion, compeller talisman expresses the concept perfectly.  Thanks for the help.  Now if I could just find a single word in any language for that concept.

Answer (score -1):

The best word I can think of that meets your requirement is "compeller". I wasn't sure whether it could be used as a noun like this, but according to TheFreeDictionary it can, as compeller is listed as a noun under compel and the citation references the American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, so I'm assuming it can be trusted.

Comment: Based on the discussion, compeller talisman expresses the concept perfectly. Thanks for the help. Now if I could just find a single word in any language for that concept.